# Access violation to unmanaged memory from finalizer

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++-cli, finalizer, unmanaged-memory

I tried to clean up memory of unmanaged classes from c++/cli finalizer and it gave me AcessViolation error. I do something like this:

```
MyClass::!MyClass()
{

    if(_unmanaged)
    {
    _unmanaged->Delete();
    _unmanaged = 0;
    }
}
```

Could anyone know, what the problem? Thanks for answers.

Comment: What does `_unmanaged->Delete( )` do?

Comment: _unmanaged, in my case, vtk class, Delete - standart procedure to clean up vtk objects. It may be another method of unmanaged class in any case it will be AccessViolation.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're setting `_unmanaged` to zero?

Comment: This suggests that _unmanaged no deleted twice

Comment: And are you sure you've not either a) already deleted `_unmanaged` or b) never actually created it in the first place?

Comment: Yes, i am sure about a) and b).

Comment: Have you switched on unmanaged debugging and debugged into it?

Comment: No, i not debugging unmanaged. I think, problem not in _unmanaged. It is look like closing unmanaged memory to use from clr in finalizing stage.

Comment: Can you post more of your code?

Comment: No, i can't - security policy.

Comment: Could you post your destructor code at least?

Comment: MyClass::~MyClass()
 {
  this->!MyClass();
 }
 MyClass::!MyClass()
 {

  if(_unmanaged)
  {
  _unmanaged ->Delete();
  _unmanaged = 0;
  }
 }

Comment: It is all about cleaning in this class.

Comment: I can't see anything which would cause an access violation here. It has to be something else in your code. Sorry I can't be of more help...

Comment: How are you initializing `_unmanaged`? Are you explicitly setting it to null in the constructor and initializing it later? Are you doing the real initialization in the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have one guess.

Finalizer works from it's own thread, so when you try to dispose your object manually race conditions can occur.

I saw your comment about "already deleted object" but I would check it once again.

```
MyClass::~MyClass()
{
   this->!MyClass();

   GC::KeepAlive(this);
}
```

Comment: The finalizer works on its own thread, but if something has a reference to the object, which is required in order to call Dispose, then the garbage collector won't touch it.